# Register routes dynamically per domain (multi-tenant)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

Is it possible to register routes AFTER application_start?  In our multi-tenant application, customers are creating their own websites (www.domaina.com, www.domainb.com, etc) and these all point to our application.  The customer can define which pages they want for their website.  So, we could register all the corresponding routes in AppStart, but if the customer adds a new route, then how will the application know to serve that url?  I tried registering routes in BeginRequest, but that doesnt seem to do well.

Basically, I need to have different routes depending on which domain the application is entered through.  Anyone done anything like this?

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom route.

```
public class MyRoute : RouteBase
{
    private readonly RoutesRepository _routesRepository;

    public MyRoute(RoutesRepository routesRepo)
    {
        _routesRepository = routesRepo;
    }

    #region Overrides of RouteBase

    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        //Here you get all custom urls(that users have created) for current domain. Then try to match request url with urls from collection. If ok then create route and return it.
    }

    ...

    #endregion
}
```

Another option: 
You can add custom constraint to route. Constraint will check if current domain has access to specific page.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the routing at runtime, but once you changed it, it's the same to all the domains that use the same application. One solution can be is to use different instances of this application for each routing configuration, which can than be configured based on the instance specific domain name.